# Soccer score web service

Tags: web-services

Does anyone know any web service that I can retrieve information about soccer games?

I want to create an app to show this info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How much have you got to spend?

This sort of information (unless it's old - i.e. not "today's" scores) tends to cost a lot of money. Newspapers pay a lot to get sports feeds, so unless you want historical data, it's unlikely you'll get anything for free.